# Insert/Delete methods for self-referencing belongsToMany association

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I’m struggling with a self-referencing belongsToMany association. To be clear I have a Models table and each model can have multiple accessories, which are also models. So I have a linking table, Accessories, with a model_id (the “parent” model) and an accessory_id (the “child” model).

I finally found how to declare this in the ModelsTable :

```
$this->belongsToMany('AccessoryModels', [
    'className' => 'Models',
    'through' => 'Accessories',
    'foreignKey' => 'model_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'accessory_id'
]);
$this->belongsToMany('ParentAccessoryModels', [
    'className' => 'Models',
    'through' => 'Accessories',
    'foreignKey' => 'accessory_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'model_id'
]);
```

I also got it working to retrieve these data in the Models view.

But I now have some issues for the addAccessory (and deleteAccessory) method in the Models controller and views.

Here is it in the controller :

```
public function addAccessory($id = null)
{
    $model = $this->Models->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    if ($this->getRequest()->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $accessory = $this->getRequest()->getData();
        if ($this->Models->link($model, [$accessory])) {
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view', $model->id]);
        }
    }
    $models = $this->Models
        ->find('list', ['groupField' => 'brand', 'valueField' => 'reference'])
        ->order(['brand' => 'ASC', 'reference' => 'ASC']);
    $this->set(compact('model', 'models'));
}
```

The view is only a select dropdown with the list of all available models (I'm using a plugin, AlaxosForm, but it takes the original CakePHP `control()` function behaviour) :

```
echo $this->AlaxosForm->label('accessory_id', __('Accessory'), ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']);
echo $this->AlaxosForm->control('accessory_id', ['options' => $models, 'empty' => true, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control']);
echo $this->AlaxosForm->button(___('Submit'), ['class' => 'btn btn-default']);
```

The problem is that the `addAccessory()` function won't work when getting the submitted data from the form. I see the problem, as when posting the inserted values, only an array with one accessory_id is given (for example `['accessory_id' => 1]` and the `link()` doesn't know what to do with it. So I think it’s an issue about data formatting but don’t see how to get it correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully get it... your problem is that in your frontend you can only select a single model, and you want to select multiple instead? In any case it might be helpful if you'd show the corresponding template code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the question with the template. My issue is that the `addAccessory()` function won't work and I'm pretty sure it's because of the sent date from the submitted form (which is in the form of `['accessory_id' => 2]`). But maybe the issue is in the `addAccessory()`… not sure.

Comment: Ok, so from looking at it, you only want to link a single `AccessoryModel`?

Comment: Yes, only one at the time for the add method. But then of course multiple ones are stored (and displayed in the view Model template and this part works well).

Comment: I see. With the shown data you should receive an error?, as the link saving mechanism expects an entity object, and will try to access an object method on the passed value! Please always post errors (including the stacktrace) if you receive any, as it greatly helps to identify problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving links (like any other ORM saving methods) requires to pass entities, anything else will either be ignored, or trigger errors.

So you have to use the `accessory_id` to obtain an entity first, something like:

```php
$accessoryId = $this->getRequest()->getData('accessory_id');
$accessory = $this->Models->AccessoryModels->get($accessoryId);
```

Furthermore you need to use the model/table that corresponds to the target entities (second argument) that you want to link (to the first argument), ie you'd have to use `AccessoryModels`, like:

```php
$this->Models->AccessoryModels->link($model, [$accessory])
```

See also

- **[Coobook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Associate Many To Many Records](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#associate-many-to-many-records)**

Comment: It works, thanks ! For those having the same issue, I also had to change in the controller from `$this->Models->link($model, [$accessory])` to `$this->Models->AccessoryModels->link($model, [$accessory])`.

Comment: @randomUserName Sorry, I've overlooked that one. I've updated my answer.